# Help with Btree homework

Tags: b-tree

I need to do a preorder traversal of a Btree, and among other things, print the following information for each page (which is the same thing as a node):

1. The B-Tree page number
2. The value of each B-Tree page pointer (e.g., address, byte offset, RRN).

My questions are:
1. How do you figure out the byte offset? What is it offset from?
2. Isn't the RRN the same as the page number?

Note: A Btree is NOT A BINARY TREE.  Btrees can have multiple keys in each node, and a node with n keys has n+1 child pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The byte offset is probably the offset of the record from the beginning of the page.

I think the RRN is the relative record number. So if a record is the 5th record in the page, its RRN would be 5.

You need to know the page layout to know how to interpret the information in a page/node. Many solutions are possible.

What code do you have to write, and what code is given to you? I need to know more about exactly what the assignment is asking you to do before I can be of any more help.

Comment: The code for B-tree creation is given, sort of.  I need to make a program that traverses the B-tree, and outputs information about it.  The program can use the other files that were used in constructing the B-tree.  The main point of the program is so that the user can know the characteristics of the Btree.

Comment: If RRN refers to the keys in the page and not the page itself, then if every page has 5 keys, are the RRN numbers going to always be from 1 to 5, or does every single key in the tree have a unique RRN?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what an RRN is, but I think it means "relative record number". If this is the case, then if every page have 5 keys, then an RRN will always be an integer from 1 to 5. Another way to explain it is, it uniquely identifies and record on a page. It wouldn't be a bad idea to double check this with someone.


If your given the code for the Btree's data structures, then those files should explain how to extract the information from a node.